# How to let function continue if a return is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a chat application and right now i'm working on the ability to create a new chat. To prevent the user to be able to create duplicate chats, i came up with this.

user1 is pre-defined. user2 is defined by entering it into a form. handleSubmit checks if this already exist and if "isChat" returns an id from my database the user gets redirected to the already existing chat.

I have trouble with the other part. If "isChat" is undefined my function wont continue and stops at the first await function.

```
  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const isChat = await getChatId(user1, user2);
    if (isChat) {
      setChatId(isChat);
      setDefinedPartnerName(true);
    } else {
      await initiateNewChat(user1, user2, messages);
      const chatId = await getChatId(user1, user2);
      setChatId(chatId);
      setDefinedPartnerName(true);
    }
  }
```

This is my fetch for this:

```
//Get chat ID by user1 and user2
export async function getChatId(user1, user2) {
  return fetch(`/api/${user1}/${user2}`, {
    method: 'GET'
  })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
      }
      return response;
    })
    .then(response => response.json());
}
```

This function cant return anything if there are no records for these two users.

Comment: Yes. If there is no correspondence between the two users on the server mongoose tells me "Cannot read property '_id' of undefined"

Comment: The first part of the function works fine. (if there already has been correspondence)

Comment: You should have a `.catch(err => {return {}})` block in second part if there's any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it on my express route.

My express route has a try...catch function and i gave the catch part of it a `response.json(false);`

It is a hotfix. But I really don't want to spend a lot of time on backend stuff.

Thanks for your help everyone

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the error fell through "throw"?

try:

```
export async function getChatId(user1, user2) {
  return fetch(`/api/${user1}/${user2}`, {
    method: 'GET'
  })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        // throw new Error(response.statusText);
        return false;
      }else{
        return response;
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json());
}
```

The syntax for error handling can also be improved:
https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/09/13/fetch-and-errors/

Comment: I get this `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.json is not a function``